# Python: Dealing with overlapping datasets

Tags: python, pandas, loops, regression

I am facing a problem in dealing with overlapping datasets.

I have a dataframe now with 3 columns:

Column 1 (Day): 1,2,3,4.....

Column 2 (Number of new case): 3,1,0,0.....

Column 3 (Cumulative number of cases): 3,4,4,4....

I need to find the reg.coef (x=Day and y=Cumulative) for each datasets and append the results in a new column (as shown in the photo below). The datasets are as below:

Set1: Day1 - Day7

Set2: Day2 - Day8

Set3: Day3 - Day9

Set...: Day n+1 - Day n+7

Should I use iloc? or Is there any better way to do this?

Many many thanks!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snOiO.png)

Comment: Have a look at [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: @jorijnsmit it works. Thank you!